# How does Ansible find group_vars when working with Terraform

Tags: ansible, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, ansible-inventory, terragrunt

I'm setting up a project using terraform and Ansible. After Terraform creates all the needed resources, I need to provision the servers using Ansible, where I am using the following:

```
# provisioner "local-exec" {
#     environment = {
#       ANSIBLE_SSH_RETRIES       = "30"
#       ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING = "False"
#     }
#     command = "ansible-playbook ${var.ec2_ansible_playbook} --extra-vars env_name=${var.env} -u ubuntu -i ${aws_eip.main.0.public_ip},"
#   }
```

Ansible fails to find my `group_vars`, How do I point Ansible to the correct path where `group_vars` are located? Previously, I was only using Ansible and I would run something like

```
ansible-playbook provision.yml -i inventory/prod/hosts
```

Ansible wouldn't have any problems finding group_vars since they were sitting at the same location as the hosts. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the `working-dir` like mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec.html#working_dir)

I think per default it uses the module directory as working directory.